# jquery sum price and quantity in table

Tags: jquery, plugins, html-table

How to get total sum of vaues in table (i'm a totaly new to jquery):

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="cm_sum">
    <td>description 1</td>
    <td><input type="text" style="width: 40px;" class="cm_quantity" placeholder="Kolicina" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="cm_price" value="230" />&euro;</td>
    <td><a href="#" id="removeCustomTableRow" class="icon-remove" title="odstrani" ></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cm_sum">
    <td>To je malo daljsi opis izdelka tukaj. Kaj pa ce je se daljsi?</td>
    <td><input type="text" style="width: 40px;" class="span3 cm_quantity" placeholder="Kolicina" value="1"></td>
    <td>230,00 &euro;</td>
<td><a href="#" id="removeCustomTableRow" class="icon-remove" data-placement="bottom" title="odstrani" ></a></td>
    </tr>
```

I'm writin a jQuery plugin (notice that some rows have a price with input text field and some don't).

currently i have which of course it doesn't work:

```
(function ( $ ) {
 $.fn.priceSum = function() {

    $("tr.cm_sum").each(function() {

        var $quantityObject = $(this).find("td").eq(1);
        var $priceObject = $(this).find("td").eq(2);

        alert('quantity: ' + $quantityObject.val() + ", price: " + $priceObject.val());
    });

};

}( jQuery ));
```

Thanks

Comment: Just a side note plugin is more often used to make a reusable functionality and you are not using it in the way generally plugin in written, Probably you can just write this in a function.

Comment: when are you showing the sum ? on click or on enter? please provide the full code so we can assist you or create a fiddle and edit the link

Comment: PLease note the eq index starts at 0 so if you have two tds it should be 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2

Comment: You want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6B565/